# Expressing "To give something an X spin/bias" in German

Tags: meaning, translation, word-usage, english-to-german, german-to-english

I am looking for a good way to express sentences such as,

1. This newspaper gives the news a conservative spin/bias.
2. We need to put a positive spin on the bad news.

I see in some dictionaries an almost literal,

"...gibt den Nachrichten einen konservativen Dreh.", and
"...den schlechten Nachrichten einen positiven Dreh geben",

but there aren't too many examples of this on the internet, so I'm not 100% sure. Other possibilities for sentence 1. seem to be using "Ausrichtung", but still, "eine konservative Ausrichtung geben" doesn't seem to be produce many results either.

Can anybody help me out here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of _einen Dreh geben_ one can also say _einen Drall geben_. I find this metaphor better, because _Drall_ is the rotational impulse (i.e., the spin). Actually, it is the impulse and not the rotation itself that is given to something.

Comment: "Dreh" has some sort of connotation of *manipulation* or trick to it - Some more than *spin*, I think

Comment: @tofro: But that is exactly what "spin" is: Tatsachen verdrehen. **Drall** is the literal translation of "spin", but I wouldn't use it myself.

Comment: @Björn: "spin" is the rotation, not the impulse.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis *spin* is in my book a synonym for *bias* - being preoccupied. "Dreh" is not. "Dreh" is actively manipulating things.

Comment: To give spin is manipulating toward a bias.

Comment: "Spin", when used in this context, means exactly to bias something through manipulation. There is even a news show in the US called "The no spin zone", which suggests that they are telling only the facts (of course, they are not). It can also be used as a verb: "This newspaper spins the news according to their political beliefs."

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Danke fuer deine Vorschlaege! Wie waere es mit dem Wort "Anstrich"? 

"Die Zeitung verleiht den Nachrichten einen linken/konservativen Anstrich." ?

Comment: @Mark: "Anstrich" geht schon, aber das klingt m.E. etwas zu harmlos.

Answer (score 4):

The most used translations for *bias* are *Ausrichtung*, *Beeinflussung*, *Voreingenommenheit*, and if more technical, then *Verzerrung* - or their adjectives or verbs. Otherwise, some alternate constructions are more useful:

> This newspaper gives the news a conservative spin/bias.
>
> Diese Zeitung verleiht den Nachrichten eine konservative *Ausrichtung*.

and

> We need to put a positive spin on the bad news.
>
> Wir müssen die Nachrichten positiver *ausrichten*.

and

> This newspaper is politically biased.
>
> Diese Zeitung ist politisch *voreingenommen*.

In technical contexts, you may read *Verzerrung*. However, especially in electronics, the English word *Bias* (capitalised as noun) is preferred even in German, because the word *distortion* also means *Verzerrung* but describes a complete different phenomenon.

Comment: If the newspaper is politically biased it does not necessarily mean it's influenced. IMHO the right translation for being biased is "voreingenommen sein".

Comment: @infinitezero yes, this is a better translation, I edited it.

Comment: @rexkogitans Danke! Wie waere es mit "Anstrich"? Die Zeitung verleiht den Nachrichten einen konservativen Anstrich?

Comment: @Mark "Anstrich" finde ich nicht gebräuchlich hier.

Comment: Statt Anstrich vielleicht "Ton" oder neudeutsch "Touch"?

Comment: "Touch" came into my mind too, but IMHO Denglish should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, "*einer Geschichte einen Dreh geben*" isn't a good translation as it sounds too positive. It means that you tell a story from a somewhat different - but valid - angle. That is a quality of a good author or journalist!

By contrast, "*to give a spin/bias*" is unequivocally negative: You distort some information. If you want to have this meaning in German, you would have to use some expresssion like "*einen Sachverhalt verdreht/verzerrt wiedergeben*".

I am not sure, how I would add the type of spin, e.g., "*conservative spin*". It's definitely not "*konservativ verdreht*". Maybe I would use "allzu konservativ". In that case my disapproval is already expressed by "*allzu*" and I could indeed say "einer Geschichte eine allzu konservative Ausrichtung geben" (or "*einen ... Dreh*").

Comment: Well, "spin" of course translates to "Dreh" or "Drall". But me, as an Austrian, I really never heard of "einer Geschichte einen Dreh geben." Maybe, I would even understand it wrong and read it as "make the story more vivid."

Comment: @rexkogitans: Exactly that is my concern: You and I would generally interpret "*einen Dreh geben*" as something positive. In another answer (by @mtwde) "Pfiff" is suggested as a good translation, which is in line with your interpretation - but not with the meaning of the English original!

Answer (score 1):

"Dreh" is i.m.o understandable, formal-ish (it's what my parents are likely to say but neither my peers nor an official text would use it) and rather rare.

Propably the most formal way is "eine XY Konnotation" e.g. 1: "Die Zeitung gibt der Meldung eine konservative Konnotation" 2: "Wir müssen der schlechten Nachricht eine positive Konnottion geben". followed by "ein XY Bezug" 1: "Die Zeitung gibt der Meldung einen konservativen Bezug".

Generally you can use "etwas eine XY Note geben" or "etas einen XY Anstrich" thoght it is somewhat colloquial and I wouldn't use it for 1. (note that "etwas" is Dativ here)

In colloquial language you can use "etwas hat einen XY Touch", "etwas einen XY Touch geben". (Dativ too)

But the way I would phrase these thoughts myself is "Die Zeitung stellt die Nachrichten in ein konservatives Licht" or "Wir müssen die schlechte Nachricht in ein gutes Licht rücken". leo.org tranaslates "etw.[Akk.] ins rechte Licht rücken" with "to put sth. in perspective" and for me it feels most natural to use that idiom for anything that's beeing put in one perspective or the other.

Answer (score 1):

*To give something a certain spin* can be translated into German very well by the following metaphor:

- *Eine Sache in ein bestimmtes Licht rücken*

This matches *to give something a certain spin* pretty well, because it also has a very proactive subtone.

Within the last years, the imported term *framing* has also gained some conjuncture in German, an it is now possible to use the verb *framen* as an anglicism from *to frame*:

- *Eine Sache auf eine bestimmte Weise framen*

Other possibilities of expressing this are:

- *Eine Sache parteiisch darstellen* (*to present a thing with a certain bias*)
- *Eine Sache aus einer bestimmten Perspektive darstellen.* (*to present a thing from a certain angle / a certain perspective*)

Though the metaphor

- *Einer Sache einen bestimmten Dreh geben*

would be understood - it is the literal translation  of *to give a thing a certain spin* -, I do not think it would be used idiomatically.

Comment: Danke! Konnte man auch einfach sagen, "...den Nachrichten einen konservativen Bias geben"?

Comment: @Mark Nein. Bias _hat_ man, aber man kann ihn nicht _weitergeben_.

Comment: Thanks. Noch ein Versuch mit dem Wort "Bias" :)

"Die Sendung verdreht/verzerrt die Nachrichten, so dass sie einen konservativen/linken Bias haben."

Comment: @Mark: Ja, vielleicht eher: _Die Sendung verdreht die Fakten, sodass ..._.

Comment: @Mark Ein Bias (und auch ein Spin) äußert sich vor allem im Kommentar, im Ton, und in der Auswahl dessen, was und wie berichtet wird. Wenn man die Nachrichten _verdreht_ oder _verzerrt_, dann ist das schon deutlich stärkere Manipulation. (Das impliziert für mich, dass das, was ich berichte, nicht einmal _streng genommen_ wahr ist.)

Answer (score 0):

First ... what is a spin?

> Public relations term, referring to slightly altering facts to portray a desired version of a story.
>
> A description or the act of describing negative events in an overly favorable way. Advertising Copy or political hyperbole, especially when intentionally misleading.

[1](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=spins), [2](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/spin)

From my point of view *Dreh* or *Verdrehung* are indeed your best choices. Or you can take a look at these words, where finassiert/finassieren may be another good choice.

> [fi­nas­sie­rt](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/finassieren)
>
> [Kniff](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kniff) (3b)
>
> [Pfiff](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pfiff) (2b)

or very far fetched

> [Winkelzug](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Winkelzug)

**Edit**:

> (der Geschichte) eine neue/andere Richtung geben

Comment: Meines Erachtens keine gute Antwort, da dsie die negative Konnotation von "spin" komplett ignoriert.

Answer (score -1):

»Ausrichtung« is okay for case (1):

> Diese Zeitung hat eine [eher] konservative Ausrichtung / politische
>   Färbung / Tendenz.
>
> Diese Zeitung ist [eher] konservativ ausgerichtet / gefärbt.

To »Tendenz« there is also an adjective for biased behaviour:

> Dieser Kommentar ist tendenziös.
>
> tendenziöse Berichterstattung

Case (2) is more difficult, I would propose the following:

> Wir dürfen nicht nur schlechte Nachrichten bringen.

Comment: That is not nearly the translation of use of the word "spin" here! It refers to what is done with the news, not to the newspaper. In journalism, it can be translated as "Darstellung" (of the news), which is not nearly the same as "Ausrichtung" (of the newspaper). **"Diese Zeitung gibt den Nachrichten einen konservative Darstellung"** or **"... einen konservativen Dreh"** or even **"... einen konservativen Schlag"**. Also **"Wir müssen die schlechten Nachrichten einen positiven Dreh geben"** or **"... positiv darstellen"**

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Bevor ich bei Zeitungen von _Schlag_ oder _Dreh_ rede, würde ich eher von _Tendenz_ sprechen.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Well, "Färbung" is indeed quite fitting, even though it's usually rather descriptive than prescriptive.

Comment: @Pollitzer: Würde ich aber nicht. Es ist keine Tendenz. Das Wort "spin" bedeutet mehr oder weniger wörtlich, dass man Tatsachen **verdreht**. "Färbung" ist da schon näher. Das gilt übrigens auch für Berichtgebung in Fernsehsendungen, Texten auf Pamphleten, Aussprachen von Politikern, usw.